# Mulesoft Parse Template - change location dynamically

Tags: mule, mulesoft

Is it possible to replace the location property of the Parse Template? Instead of hardcoding in the location like so

[image: hardcoded location]

Is it possible to replace this with a variable value that points to a path at runtime?

[image: location with variable]

i have tried replacing the location with a variable but the project then fails to deploy because it cannot find that path. When the POST request comes in it states what file it wants parsed. Then we would ideally like to tell the parse template to go fetch that file but thus far i cant see anything that could help me online

Any suggestions would be very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to use an expression in the location attribute. Note that in the screenshot we can see that it is missing the Fx button to switch to expression mode, like the the Target Value attribute has.